# Parse Cloud Functions - restrict access to single users

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I'm currently experimenting with Parse Cloud Functions.
The following simple example already worked well:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", async (request) => {
    return "Hi " + request.params.name;
});
```

---

In my apps I login as a user before making any request so I want to restrict access to this function by objectId of the user.
The docs give the following example for validation:

```js
requireUserKeys: {
    accType : {
      options: 'reviewer',
      error: 'Only reviewers can get average stars'
    }
  }
```

So I added this validation to my request (and I require masterKey for validation as normal users are not allowed to read User objects):

[image: documentation]

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", async (request) => {
    return "Hi " + request.params.name;
}, {
    validateMasterKey: true,
    requireUserKeys: {
        objectId: {
            options: "ABCD1234", // dummy id
            error: "Unauthorized"
        }
    }
});
```

---

If I now make a request as the logged in user with the objectId "ABCD1234" I get the error message "Unauthorized", so the validation does not work as intended.

How do you implement user restriction correctly for Cloud functions?
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the `validateMasterKey: true` option, the cloud code function will run only when passing the master key, regardless of the logged in user. In fact, you should either use `validateMasterKey` option or `requireUserKeys` option. It does not make sense to use both of them at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Take a look above, I added a picture from the documentation. It says it uses the masterKey for validation. The other one would be requireMaster.

Comment: Have you tried to switch objectId to _id or id?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to use `requireUserKeys` before, but you could do something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", async (request) => {
    const authorizedUsers = ["ABCD1234"];
    if(authorizedUsers.indexOf(request.user?.id) == -1) throw "Unauthorized";

    //if you need to do any work that requires masterkey, you can always use the {useMasterKey: true} parameter with your Parse request
    return "Hi " + request.params.name;
 }
});
```